# Xamarin: Elements are cut off/not rendered in ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, scrollviewer

I've following situation.

```
<ScrollView BackgroundColor="DeepPink">
    ...
    <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <ContentView Opacity="{Binding  ViewProvider.IsCancelling, Converter={StaticResource BoolToOpacityConverter}}" Content="{Binding ViewProvider.CurrentView}"/>
    </Grid>
    ...
</ScrollView>
```

The Content View contains multiple elements and one of them is a StackLayout with BindableLayout.ItemsSource

```
<StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Rings}" Margin="12,0,0,0">
    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            ...
        </DataTemplate>
    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</StackLayout>
```

The Rings will be added by different actions while the View is open. As soon as this happens, the height of the ScrollViewer increases, but the parts below are cut off or just not rendered. *(It cut's the height off, which the rings are using - I guess because the Grid doesn't resize? But why?)*

[image: ScrollViewer Issue with Xamarin]

I've tried to call **InvalidateMeasure()** and **ForceLayout()** after adding rings but without any changes. Any ideas?

**Edit**

As requested in the comments I've uploaded a simple demo on github to reproduce this issue.
https://github.com/Valronicon/ScrollViewerIssue

Thank you!

**Edit 2**

I was able to fix this by wrapping the ScrollViewer within an additional Grid. Don't know why it works, but it works...

Comment: Can't you just delete the `Grid` element and use the `StackLayout` with `FillAndExpand` ?

Comment: Unfortunately the same behaviour :/

Comment: Would you mind sharing us a baisc, minimal project to test ? You can upload it to github and attach the link here .

Comment: @WenxuLi-MSFT Thanks for the reply. I've uploaded a demo to github. https://github.com/Valronicon/ScrollViewerIssue

Comment: I tried to download your demo and run it. After I clicked the add button, I successfully added a message below, and the rest of the frames were loaded normally.

Comment: With Android? Click the Button only once. After 2nd click it seems to reload everything somehow and everything is displayed correct.

Comment: When I tried the project you provided, everything was normal, and the situation in your picture did not appear. The Android emulator I used.

Comment: Known issue for a while: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/13597

Comment: I was able to fix this by wrapping the ScrollViewer within an additional Grid. Don't know why it works, but it did.

Answer (score 0):

As Rich Mentioned wrapping the scrollview in a grid seemed to solve this issue for me as well, so im posting it as an answer

```
<Grid> 
    <ScrollView>
    ...
    </ScrollView>
</Grid>
```